# Trying to pass selected value from dropdown and substituting in path for redirection

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Cluster()
{
    var clusters= [
        {
            value:1,
            label: "NA1"
        }
    ];

    const history = useHistory();
    const [result,ddlvalue]= useState(clusters.label);
    const routeChange = e =>{
        ddlvalue(e.label);
        let path = 'inventory/cluster/'+result; 
        console.log(path)
        history.push(path);
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <Select options={clusters} onChange={routeChange}/> 
            <h1>{result}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Cluster;
```

console.log(path) is giving me inventory/cluster/undefined, i am a beginner in react and facing this issue. Looking for some guidance.

Comment: `clusters` is an array, so `clusters.label` is undefined. Did you mean to use `clusters[0].label` instead? Additionally, React state updates are asynchronously processed, so you can't enqueue a state update and expect to use the updated state within the same render cycle/callback scope. I don't see the point of using any state here since you can skip the state update and just use the current label value from the `onChange` event.

Comment: Oh my bad yes I didnt realize, let me check

Comment: So I was trying to use whatever value i select in dropdown, like if there are 4 values the label should be taken and substituted. Like  [{value:1,label: "NA1"},{value:2,label: "NA2"}] and once i select NA1 or NA2 in dropdown, they should be substituted in my path

Comment: Do you need help with that?

Comment: Yes I am looking but landing in issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React state updates are asynchronously processed, so you can't enqueue a state update and expect to use the updated `result` state value within the same render cycle/callback scope. Just use the current label value from the onChange event to form the next target `path` value. Add a leading `"/"` so the link is treated as an absolute path, i.e. `"/inventory/cluster/" + e.label`.

```
function Cluster() {
  var clusters = [
    {
      value: 1,
      label: "NA1"
    },
    {
      value: 2,
      label: "NA2"
    },
    {
      value: 3,
      label: "NA3"
    },
    {
      value: 4,
      label: "NA4"
    }
  ];

  const history = useHistory();
  const [result, ddlvalue] = useState(clusters[0].label);

  const routeChange = (e) => {
    ddlvalue(e.label);
    let path = "/inventory/cluster/" + e.label;
    console.log(path);
    history.push(path);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Select options={clusters} onChange={routeChange} />
      <h1>{result}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit trying-to-pass-selected-value-from-dropdown-and-substituting-in-path-for-redirec]